# Is it possible to grind counter-top as a DIY job?

Tags: countertops, granite, angle-grinder

Every time we wash dishes in the sink water splashes and sprays in all directions, even if we are careful to minimize that.  Of course we wipe it dry once done.  Still, I became concerned with *thin strip of caulk between counter-top and backsplash right next to the sink gradually becoming darker and darker*.  I'm guessing, because of it being damp too often, bacteria favors that location (note that *same strip of caulk to the right of sink is of normal color*):
[image: 1]

Had an idea for some time, and recent stumble on [several](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/289987/moving-faucet-hole-in-granite-countertop) [related](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211446/hole-in-granite-countertop-for-kitchen-faucet-slightly-small) [questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/191196/whats-best-to-stick-granite-backsplash-to-granite-countertop) last week nudged me, so

**Q:  Is it be possible to grind two shallow incline areas on the counter-top to allow water to drain naturally?**

Kinda, like this:
[image: 5]

Concerns that I have:

1. **Can it be a DIY job?**  Thinking of using [grinding](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B8FX6TCH) [wheels and tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BHSYLMZ2) like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09L7YJ96B).
   How to keep the incline perfectly level - *esp. using handheld angle grinder*?
2. **Would the resulting surface need to be polished?**
   I tried grinding a throw-away piece of granite and the rough result looks like it's actually going to absorb water quite readily - that will defeat the purpose.
3. **Would this actually help - as I hope?**

**Edit** 2024-01-08:
Guys, thank you all for your comments, they all have been very helpful to re-asses the situation.  Upvoted the ones with most caution or advice.  I agree that even if this worked, it would be too messy and complicated for DIY, esp. with no experience working with granite.
I'm glad i asked! :)

P.S. If anyone of you puts it as answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: Can it be done DIY, yes.  I would like to practice a lot on throw away stuff quite a bit before doing it where it needs to look good.  I think it is a multi step process, with grinding being the first step.  Sanding/polishing and maybe sealing following.

Comment: 3. Would this actually help - as I hope? Unless the water is pooling at the backsplash due to negative slope it's doubtful! It might help minimally but I think it would be a 'long run for a short slide'. It would still leave that area damp until it air dries. I'll let the countertop guys answer whether it can be done.

Comment: This is *not* an easy job to do well; and it's a very expensive mistake when done wrong. Call a few granite fabrication shops and ask about it. You will have to pay for it but their specialized tooling and practiced skill is worth it here

Comment: Yeah, the more i think about it, the more i'm inclined to agree with all of you guys.  Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that I would use a die grinder to get a nice channel shape. Something like a box of 12×24 tile would make a nice stable, elevated surface next to the work for stabilizing your hand.

Comment: Various locales are forbidding installation of "engineered stone" (https://www.abc.net.au/news/2023-12-14/engineered-stone-ban-australia-kitchen-benchtops-alternatives/103218014, https://attilasnaturalstone.com.au/the-dark-side-of-engineered-stone-why-its-being-banned-and-what-you-can-use-instead) because the fine particles released in cutting damage lungs. Check the counter top material before grinding!

Comment: #3 = no. So forget about the whole thing except putting an actual fillet of caulk where the backsplash meets the top. "because of it being damp too often" -no it's because the bead of caulk has delaminated from one or both, which they always do after a year or so on a new install, as the splash is attached to the wall and the cab settles on the floor. Do the under-mount sink again while you're at it. - **100%** *clear* silicone.

Comment: Don't do it.   Even if you are successful (and you won't be) you'll still get water back there.   Clean it and re-caulk it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compilation of comments that shoulda been answers:

1. Yes it can be done DIY, anything can be DIY.

   - Practice, practice, practice! It's not an easy job.
2. You'll need some sort of jig to ensure your lines run nice and straight and are at a consistent slope.
3. You'll need to polish the heck out of it to get it to look like the rest of the top.
4. It probably won't help much unless you're actually getting water pooling, because the surface still needs to air dry.
5. Replace the caulk with 100% clear silicone so it stops getting under the existing caulk due to a broken caulk bead.
6. If you're going to do this, get a counter top company to come do it for you. It'll be cheaper than replacing the whole counter top when you screw it up.